# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.c.ang.c()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, google-play-services

There seems to be some issue with google services. There is no trace back to my app. Here is the stack trace of the issue as seen on Crashlytics.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.c.ang.c()' on a null
>   object reference
>
> com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt$zzc.zzasj (Unknown Source)
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt$zzc.isConnected (Unknown Source)
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt.handleMessage (Unknown Source)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:189) android.os.HandlerThread.run
>   (HandlerThread.java:61)

I'm using play services version 9.6.1

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.1.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':CustomBrowser-release')
    compile project(':PayU-release')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: please share here your full gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Try this play services:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

Comment: How will that help?

Comment: my last project i am facing same problem. i change this version solve my problem. you please check this play services i think, this play service help full for you.